# Есть некий код, надо получить список всех объектов ( переменных) и вывести статистику использования памяти по каждому объекту

Tags: python, объекты, память, переменные

Есть некий код на Python, надо получить список всех объектов (переменных) кроме внутренних пайтоновских, и вывести статистику по использованию памяти по каждому объекту.

Осталось понять с чего начать и как через `dir()` получить только нужные мне объекты? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что сработает, но можно попробовать так:

```
o=dir() #пустой
d=list(set(o) - set(dir())
import sys
[sys.getsizeof(x) for x in d]
```

Comment: d получается пустым, как и результирующая строка , пытаюсь понять почему)

Comment: Наоборот. d=list(set(dir())-set(o)). Потому что иначе вы убираете из set(o) всё, что есть в set(dir()), и ничего не добавляете. в set(o) ещё нет "o", оно появится в set(dir()).